# Error : WARN Low open file descriptor limit configured for the process. Current value: 4096, recommended value: 10000

Tags: docker, dockerfile, aws-fargate

I am trying to place a container in AWS Fargate, getting the error " WARN Low open file descriptor limit configured for the process. Current value: 4096, recommended value: 10000.  -- Error: Input("Error opening spec file: No such file or directory (os error 2)") "

Can someone please help me to fix the issue

DockerFile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get -y update

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get -y install tzdata

RUN apt install -y cmake pkg-config libssl-dev git build-essential clang libclang-dev curl

RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | bash -s -- -y

ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"

RUN rustup toolchain install nightly-2020-09-28 && rustup default nightly-2020-09-28 && rustup override 
set nightly-2020-09-28

COPY ./polkadex-aura-node/ /polkadex-aura-node/

RUN cd /polkadex-aura-node &&  cargo build --release

RUN cd /polkadex-aura-node/scripts/ && ./createCustomSpec.sh

RUN echo "fs.file-max = 100000" >> /etc/sysctl.conf

RUN ulimit -n 90000

RUN echo "* soft nofile 65535" >> /etc/security/limits.conf

RUN echo "* hard nofile 65535" >> /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Tried the last four line to fix the issue but not working.

Answer (score 0):

add to your systemd service following configuration:

LimitNOFILE=10000